# Conflict on EntityState.Modified because two objects of same model Class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I need to track and store the modifications. In order to do that I am thinking to apply following technique:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
{
   var rcd_BFEmployee = db.Employees.Find(employee.Id);

   if(rcd_BFEmployee.Email != employee.Email)
   {
       // Other Stuff
   }

   db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
   // Here is the confliction
}
```

> Attaching an entity of type 'Models.Employee' failed because another
>   entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

How can I force to Apply Modficiation State only on the object I am receiving as the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You retrieve an instance of `Employee` with `Employees.Find(employee.Id)`, this instance is now attached to the `DbContext` and is being tracked. Any calls to `SaveChanges` will update this entity in the database.

At the bottom of your code you are trying to attach and track the passed in instance `employee` with a call to `db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;`. This points to the same data store record as the previously retrieved instance on the first line.

---

### Solutions

All of these are viable solutions:

---

Do not call `db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;`, use the `rcd_BFEmployee` instance you retrieved and make changes on it. You can copy state from `employee` to this instance.

---

Attach `employee` directly and not retrieve `rcd_BFEmployee` at all.

---

Retrieve `rcd_BFEmployee` but use [AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) so it will not be tracked by the `DbContext`.

```
var rcd_BFEmployee = db.Employees.AsNoTracking().Single(i => i.Id == employee.Id);
```

---

Retrieve `rcd_BFEmployee` but detach the instance so it will not be tracked by the `DbContext`.

```
Context.Entry(rcd_BFEmployee).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Attach Method of your DbSet Employees?

```
db.Employees.Attach(employee);
```